# Is there a standard schema for video metadata?

Tags: video, schema

I am looking for a schema to hold video metadata such as Title, Source, Description, Transcription, Copyright date, URL, etc.

It would be used to store information about the video in a database and make that searchable.

Is there a standard XSD or other schema for this type of data?

Comment: You mean a _single_ standard?  I don't think so ;)

Comment: well an industry standard or one that is used by popular video sites like youtube, vimeo, etc..

Comment: external to the file or internal?

Comment: external, for storing and searching on the metadata from a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no THE STANDARD for doing that, it would involve a large number of fields and descriptions which  may be unnecessary for a single format.

So each format has its own method of Meta-Data storage
But since you want to implement it in  an external file (or database),

You almost certainly have to implement your own schema, its not very hard.

You haven't mentioned what back end you're using, SQL would be good if you're database if going to be reasonably large, and easy to search if you index the right fields.

OR

You can use XML / XSD combination if you like.

Answer (score 3):

I think this Google/Bing/Yahoo schema construct is probably as close to a "standard" as we have right now. http://schema.org/VideoObject

Answer (score 1):

There is the **[MPEG 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-7)** standard, but it is my impression that it is not (yet) widely supported.  It sounds very much like what you are asking for.  A blurb snippet from Wikipedia:

> MPEG-7 is a **multimedia content description standard**. It was standardized in ISO/IEC 15938 (Multimedia content description interface). This description will be associated with the content itself, to allow fast and efficient searching for material that is of interest to the user. MPEG-7 is formally called Multimedia Content Description Interface. ... **It uses XML to store metadata**, and can be attached to timecode in order to tag particular events, or synchronise lyrics to a song, for example.
>
> There are many applications and application domains which will benefit from the MPEG-7 standard. A few application examples are:

- Digital library: Image/video catalogue, musical dictionary.
- Multimedia directory services: e.g. yellow pages.
- Broadcast media selection: Radio channel, TV channel.
- Multimedia editing: Personalized electronic news service, media authoring.
- Security services: Traffic control, production chains...
- E-business: Searching process of products.
- Cultural services: Art-galleries, museums...
- Educational applications.
- Biomedical applications.

Answer (score 1):

check out the the [Dublin Core Metadata Initiative](http://dublincore.org/)

The Dublin Core Metadata Initiative, or "DCMI", is an open organization engaged in the development of interoperable metadata standards that support a broad range of purposes and business models.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard called [NewsML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NewsML-G2) supported by IPTC - International Press Telecommunications Council. Its last version was published on 20th Nov 2012.
I am not sure about the adoption of the second version but the first is mostly used in NA and Asia.

Answer (score 0):

So further research has left us with MRSS (Media RSS) while this isn't a storage mechanism, it provides the standard fields that are used to both search on and store video file (and other media) content.   It also doesn't have an official XSD.